# Language specific 404 error page in cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a cloudfront distribution serving an s3 bucket. To make the page multilanguage, I added a lamba@edge function that analyzes the Accept-Language header and redirects `/<page>` to `/en/<page>` or `/de/<page>`.

The redirect happens with a 303 return code so that the users gets `/en/<page>` as the path shown in the browser and can switch languages by going to `/de/<page>`.

Works! But what is in case of a 404? If I configure a custom 404 page in S3 or cloudfront and the user requests `/de/<non-existing-page>`, he gets redirected to the custom 404 page (for example `/error-pages/404`). But that page is not translated!

Is there a way to make the 404 page language specific? Depending on if the user comes from `/en/<page>` or `/de/<page>`?

Comment: Custom error pages *should* fire an Origin Request Lambda@Edge trigger when they are fetched, if one exists on the Cache Behavior that matches the path for the custom error page.  Does that help?

Comment: Well, i would have to know If the original requests was for a Page at /de/ or /en/. Is there some way to find Out in the lamvda@edge?

Comment: At the point when a custom error page is being fetched, I believe the information about the original request is lost (not available to the request trigger).  If you are running an Origin Response trigger then you can catch and handle errors there, instead of using a custom error page, since you'd know HTTP status code and the original request path in that scenario... otherwise that might be more overhead than you want to add, unless error handling is a common need or a high priority.  Which triggers are you using, now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

1. use 2 S3 Buckets (or as many, as you have languages), one for each language and put the files for each language in the corresponding bucket
2. configure the `ErrorDocument` for each bucket to the language-specific 404 page
3. In your CloudFront distribution configure an origin and behavior for each language such that the `PathPattern` `/<language>/*` is directed to the origin fetching from the s3 bucket for language `<language>`